# Creating a matrix from a column in an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, matrix, hash

I have a dataset as an array of hashes. For example,

```
id   fruit      amount
1    grape        10
2    banana       6
3    grape        7
4    mango        15
5    strawberry   5
```

this is stored in an array of hashes as:

```
[
  {"id" => "1", "fruit" => "grape", "amount" => 10},
  {"id" => "2", "fruit" => "banana", "amount" => 6},
  ...
]
```

I need to convert the data into a form like the following (to create a matrix as the set matrix for the linear optimization problem using Rglpk):

```
id   is_grape   is_banana   is_mango    is_strawberry
1     1           0           0            0
2     0           1           0            0
3     1           0           0            0
4     0           0           1            0
5     0           0           0            1
```

and then get something like this by transposing the columns and rows:

```
[
  #1    #2    #3    #4     #5    # each column for id 1, 2, ... 
  1     0     1     0      0     # row is_grape
  0     1     0     0      0     # row is_banana
  0     0     0     1      0     # row is_mango
  0     0     0     0      1     # row is_strawberry
]
```

There could be any number of categories in a column. I want to create the values for the `is_grape`, `is_mango` type categories dynamically rather than hard code. How do I get the data in the matrix form?

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [
  {"id" => "1", "fruit" => "grape", "amount" => 10},
  {"id" => "2", "fruit" => "banana", "amount" => 6}
]

# fruits = arr.group_by { |h| h['fruit'] }.keys.map { |e| "is_#{e}" }
fruits = arr.map { |e| "is_#{e['fruit']}" }.uniq
#⇒ [ "is_grape", "is_banana" ]
arr.each_with_object([]) do |h, memo|
  e = fruits.zip([0] * fruits.size).to_h
  e['id'] = h['id']
  e["is_#{h['fruit']}"] += 1
  # e["is_#{h['fruit']}"] += h['amount'].to_i # that seems meaningful
  memo << e
end
```

Giving:

```
#⇒ [
#  [0] {
#           "id" => "1",
#    "is_banana" => 0,
#     "is_grape" => 1
#  },
#  [1] {
#           "id" => "2",
#    "is_banana" => 1,
#     "is_grape" => 0
#  }
# ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [
  {"id" => "1", "fruit" => "grape", "amount" => 10},
  {"id" => "2", "fruit" => "banana", "amount" => 6},
  {"id" => "3", "fruit" => "grape", "amount" => 7},
  {"id" => "4", "fruit" => "mango", "amount" => 15},
  {"id" => "5", "fruit" => "strawberry", "amount" => 5},
]

fruits = a.map{|h| h["fruit"]}.uniq
m = Array.new(fruits.length){[0] * a.length}
a.each{|h| m[fruits.index(h["fruit"])][h["id"].to_i - 1] = 1}
p m
```

Output:

```
[
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [
  {"id" => "1", "fruit" => "grape", "amount" => 10},
  {"id" => "2", "fruit" => "banana", "amount" => 6},
  {"id" => "3", "fruit" => "mango", "amount" => 4},
  {"id" => "7", "fruit" => "banana", "amount" => 3},
  {"id" => "5", "fruit" => "strawberry", "amount" => 7},
  {"id" => "6", "fruit" => "banana", "amount" => 1},
  {"id" => "4", "fruit" => "banana", "amount" => 3}
]

fruit_to_row = arr.map { |h| h["fruit"] }.uniq.each_with_index.
  with_object({}) { |(f,i),h| h[f] = i }
  #=> {"grape"=>0, "banana"=>1, "mango"=>2, "strawberry"=>3}

arr.each_with_index.
    with_object(Array.new(fruit_to_row.size) {Array.new(arr.size) {0}}) { |(h,i),a|
      a[fruit_to_row[h["fruit"]]][i] = 1 }
  #=> [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], grape
  #    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], banana
  #    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], mango
  #    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]] strawberry
```